# Views and Associations - Show or Index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I'm overcomplicating this..

I have a person model (id, first_name, last_name, city_id) and a city module (id, city_name).  I have an association where the person belongs_to the city and the city has_many people.  I built a _form.html.erb with simple_form and added a drop-down on the person side so the user can pick the city from a drop-down menu and stored the city ID in the city_id in the person model (int).  All of this works well.

My goal is to modify the show and index action where I show a manifest of all people such that the city name is show vs. the city_ID integer.

Right now it looks like this:
First    Last    City
Adam     Smith   1

I want it to look like this
First    Last    City
Adam     Smith   Chicago

Any ideas?  I know this is totally doable - I'm just out of ideas and can't seem to come up with an answer.

Thanks in advance.
Adam

Comment: Could you please share your views and controllers code?

Comment: person.city.city_name ?

Comment: @onurozgurozkan - how do I upload them without losing formatting?

Comment: @emrahbasman - Here is the current code:<td><%= person.city_id %></td>, are you saying I should change it to person.city.cidy_name?

Comment: There is a coding button at stackoverflow editor. `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as @emrahbasman suggested

```
<td><%= person.city.city_name %></td>
```

And, in your controller in the index method, do the following

```
@people = Person.includes(:city)
```

To avoid querying on each row when you render in the view